# Assigning references

Tags: c++, reference

Consider the following declarations:

```
Object *a;
Object *b;
```

There are two ways of assigning `a` to `b`, by value or by reference:

```
a = b; // by reference
*a = *b; // by value
```

If the declarations are:

```
Object &a;
Object &b;
```

(I know its not possible to declare them without initializing them, its just to show the types)

There are two ways of assigning `a` to `b` too, just like with pointers, by reference or by value.
Which one this code:

```
a = b;
```

is going to do? Is it possible to make it do the opposite one? (with a different syntax?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That overwrites the object referred to.

And no, it is not possible to rebind a reference so that it refers to a different object.  If you need to do that, use a pointer instead.